# How can I detect whether a symlink is broken in Bash?

Tags: bash, symlink

I run `find` and iterate through the results with `[ \( -L $F \)  ]` to collect certain symbolic links.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to determine if the link is broken (points to a non-existent file) in this scenario.

Here is my code:

```
FILES=`find /target/ | grep -v '\.disabled$' | sort`

for F in $FILES; do
    if [ -L $F ]; then
        DO THINGS
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
# test if symlink is broken (by seeing if it links to an existing file)
if [ ! -e "$F" ] ; then
    # code if the symlink is broken
fi
```

Comment: Note that the code will also be executed if the file does not exist at all. It is fine with `find` but in other scenarios (such as globs) should be combined with -h to handle this case, for instance `[ -h "$F" -a ! -e "$F"  ]`.

Comment: You're not really testing the symbolic link with this approach.

Comment: @Calimo There is no difference.

Comment: @Melab wrong... Please test your assumptions before commenting: https://git.io/fx95w This answer is INCORRECT.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I created a link, then I removed the target file and the check was still returning true

Comment: @Camilo solution worked for me in a more general case (not with find)

Comment: FYI all: see `man test` or `man [` for the information on what `-e` means. Note that in bash, `[` itself is a command. Therefore, `!` is the first arg to it, `-e` is the 2nd arg to it, `"$F"` is the 3rd arg, `]` is the 4th arg. That's why spaces are required after the `[` and before the `]`--the first is the command name and the latter is a required argument, and commands and arguments must always be separated by spaces.

Answer (score 38):

This should print out links that are broken:

```
find /target/dir -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

You can also chain in operations to `find` command, e.g. deleting the broken link:

```
find /target/dir -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: This doesn't work well if you are actually running lots of code. Do you have a `if` solution ?

Comment: Wouldn't `find -L foo -type l` do better? From a quick test it does work and is much simpler. Of course your answer shows more features of find which is a nice thing. Disclaimer: I've been awake since stupid o'clock so maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 11):

this will work if the symlink was pointing to a file or a directory, but now is broken

```
if [[ -L "$strFile" ]] && [[ ! -a "$strFile" ]];then 
  echo "'$strFile' is a broken symlink"; 
fi
```

Comment: wouldn't the `-L "$strFile"` suffice? From the docs: `[-L FILE ] True if FILE exists and is a symbolic link.` ([source](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Comment: @Sosi could this be required in an old bash version? 2014 vs 2019, I could even dont have that version anymore :)

Comment: right! that's a great point! I didn't notice how old this was, and now I feel bad for digging it up

Comment: @Sosi I think there is no problem, an updated app version's answer is always better I guess

Comment: @Sosi We want to test if the symbolic link is working, -L is true even if the file is just a broken symlink

Answer (score 4):

This finds all files of type "link", which also resolves to a type "link". ie. a broken symlink

```
find /target -type l -xtype l
```

Comment: variant: `find -L /target -type l`

Comment: Can't you have a symlink to a symlink that isn't broken?'

Comment: GNU `find` and `-xtype` resolves the symlink all the way to the end.  If a symlink is good it will always resolve to something that is not a symlink.

Same with `-L` in GNU `find` and BSD `find`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind traversing non-broken dir symlinks, to find all orphaned links:

```
$ find -L /target -type l | while read -r file; do echo $file is orphaned; done
```

To find all files that are not orphaned links:

```
$ find -L /target ! -type l
```

Comment: But this follows non-broken symlinks to directories, which we may not want.

Comment: `/target` could be a file in which case directory traversal isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of `bash` (5.1.16) `test -e "$link"` or `[[ -e "$link" ]]` do not behave as expected, failing to recognize the link as broken.

I suggest using `readlink(1)` as well as testing for the existence of the link as follows:

```
if [[ ! -L "$link" ]]; then
    echo "Missing or not a symlink"
else
    readlink -q "$link"
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
         echo "Broken"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with:

`file $f | grep 'broken symbolic link'`

Comment: There's a few things wrong with it: 1) it follows a working symbolic link and, if the target is a file, will read the contents to try to determine its type; 2) how the output is worded may not be the same everywhere and forever; 3) if the system it's run on is in a locale other than English, it may not print the English message. Add `-h` flag to fix the first problem, and prefix it with `LANG=C` to fix the third. You may or may not consider the second problem an acceptable risk.

Answer (score -1):

If it does qualify as a symbolic link, but is „not existing“, its a broken link.

```
if [[ -h $link && ! -e $link ]] ; then
    _info "$link is a BROKEN SYMLINK"
fi
```

[REFERENCE](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/)

Comment: `-h` is described as *True if file exists and is a symbolic link.* If `-h` is true then `-e` is true.